# Libraries for date validation in C?

Tags: c, validation, date

I have a struct of values for a date.

```
struct date
{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};
```

Are there any libraries for C for quick and easy date validation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard C library function `mktime()` will convert year/month/day (really a full `struct tm`) to a `time_t`, and tell you if something went wrong.